# Triggering button click on scroll triggers multiple clicks

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to trigger button click on scroll when the scroller hits the div. below is the code which i tried but when the scroller hits the div it is triggering multiple clicks and loading next multiple set of data. Can anyone suggest me how to trigger click only once.

Thanks for the help in advance :)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var divTop = $('.hit-scroll').offset().top,
    divHeight = $('.hit-scroll').outerHeight(),
    wHeight = $(window).height(),
    windowScrTp = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (windowScrTp > (divTop+divHeight-wHeight)){
        $('body').find('.show-more button').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Note: on button click an ajax call is made which loads next set of data.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that everytime you scroll down 1px you run the `$(window).scroll`

So imagine that `windowScrTp > (divTop+divHeight-wHeight)` is equal to `200 > (168)` that means your click function would be triggered twice.

I surgess you make a variable `load` like the example below, that should stop it from loading multiple times.

```
var load = true;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var divTop = $('.hit-scroll').offset().top,
    divHeight = $('.hit-scroll').outerHeight(),
    wHeight = $(window).height(),
    windowScrTp = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (windowScrTp > (divTop+divHeight-wHeight)){
        if(load){
          load = false;
          $('body').find('.show-more button').trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
```

Inside your ajax success call I would add `load = true;`

I've created a demo than shows the idea below.

**Demo**

```js
var load = true;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowScrTp = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (windowScrTp > (200)) {
    if (load) {
      console.log("load start")
      load = false;
      $('body').find('.show-more button').trigger('click');
    }
  }
});

$('.show-more button').click(function() {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      console.log("load stop")
      load = true;
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show-more"><button>more</button></div>
```

Comment: thanks @Carsten Løvbo Andersen, i can not edit the ajax call  code as its from the third party. any other way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution more precise and working great..

```
function bindScroll(){
var divTop = $('.hit-scroll').offset().top,
divHeight = $('.hit-scroll').outerHeight(),
wHeight = $(window).height(),
windowScrTp = $(this).scrollTop();
if (windowScrTp > (divTop+divHeight-wHeight)){
       $(window).unbind('scroll');
       $('body').find('.show-more button').trigger('click');
}
```

}

$(window).scroll(bindScroll);